# How to Save Convolution Neural Network(CNN) Model Output in R?

Tags: r

I would like to copy  CNN model output as (RDS or RDA) file in R and I would like to load resultant output in some other application.

I have tried `saverds` option but it is creating Empty file in work space.

```
model1<- saveRDS("model", file = "model.rda")
```

Comment: Please add more code to make this reproducible, use junk or random data. Specify which package you're using (MXNET?)

Comment: Maybe `saveRDS(model, file = "model.rds")` ?

Comment: Yes I am using MXNET Package and  i have tried both (RDS as well as RDA) extension .

Comment: In which software would you like to load the model?

Comment: To RShiny App(Server.R).. actually I want to load model data in Server.R to Predict Image Class.